# Integrate into project custom reflectionconfig-arm64-ios

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am using graalvm to create my IPA, everything seems to work except for the fact that the classes used with reflection are not linked. I generated the file in question to make explicit the classes that require me to link at compile time but I can't understand where the file should be placed.

Comment: Are you following https://docs.gluonhq.com/client/#_config_files ?

Comment: It's ok. I found the directory in the documentation: src/main/resources/META-INF/substrate/config folder.

Comment: Now I have this error: error: org.graalvm.compiler.debug.GraalError: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "llvm-link" (in directory " XXXXX/target/client/arm64-ios/gvm/tmp/SVM-1581588190880/llvm"): error=7, Argument list too long
 at com.oracle.svm.core.graal.llvm.LLVMNativeImageCodeCache.llvmLink(LLVMNativeImageCodeCache.java:557)
 at com.oracle.svm.core.graal.llvm.LLVMNativeImageCodeCache.lambda$createBitcodeBatches$8(LLVMNativeImageCodeCache.java:432)
 at